# Unable to deploy updated ECS image to existing

Tags: amazon-ecs, xcodebuild, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to update an existing python app that's running of a Docker image on ECR, this image is deployed on ECS using Fargate, this is running fine. I want to update the image that's running on ECS by pushing it up to ECR and using CodeBuild to trigger update. I've created CodeBuild project, however, after executing the script I get this error:

```
BUILD_CONTAINER_UNABLE_TO_PULL_IMAGE: Unable to pull customer's container
image. CannotPullContainerError: 
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for .... , 
repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': 
denied: User: CodeBuild
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The codebuild project role needs to have permissions to pull from that ECR repository and
needs to authenticate to the relevant ECR registry before a push or pull:

aws ecr get-login-password --region ${your_region} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${your_aaccountId}.dkr.ecr.${your_region}.amazonaws.com